# ssh key persists even after I delete the private key from ~/.ssh -- why?

Tags: terminal, ssh, authorization

I generated ssh keys (public and private) and stored them in `~/.ssh/myServer/`.

I added the public key to the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and everything works great!

In my effort to try and understand how the keys work I deleted them and was surprised to find that I was still able to connect to the server.

Why is it that I am still able to connect without a password?

Answer (score 31):

Welcome to the wonderful world of OS X Keychain and [ssh-agent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ssh-agent.1.html)! From the man page:

> ssh-agent is a program to hold private keys used for public key authentication (RSA, DSA, ECDSA).  The
>        idea is that ssh-agent is started in the beginning of an X-session or a login session, and all other
>        windows or programs are started as clients to the ssh-agent program.  Through use of environment vari-ables variables
>        ables the agent can be located and automatically used for authentication when logging in to other
>        machines using ssh(1).

Your private key was cached in the agent and is being fetched from there to authenticate your session. OS X, via Keychain, does automatic ssh-agent caching for you because it's "user friendly". It can be a little alarming, but it's mostly a handy thing that this happens.

The default time-to-live for cached keys is forever. That's probably not a great default. It'll flush the cached keys on a logout/login-cycle or a reboot. Or you can force a flush by killing the current agent using:

```
ssh-add -D
```

You can list all credentials cached by the agent by running:

```
ssh-add -l
```

This will do the same but show the full public keys:

```
ssh-add -L
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I was really confused as to what was happening. I get it now!

Comment: @FAYNUS if this solves the problem for you please press the green checkmark on the right side to mark it as the "accepted answer"! Welcome to Ask Different!